# Kentico's webpart control ID in value in a repeater and transformation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kentico, bootstrap-accordion

I'm building out a bootstrap based accordion. It's almost there, except i need to wrap each accordion with a tab with a unique ID. My thought was to use the repeaters control ID. So how i can access this from a transformation, and also the HTML envelope?

Here is the HTML envelope from the repeater

```html
<div class="accordion" id="askUsAccordion">
  
  
</div>
```

Here is my transformation code

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="#accordionPanel<%# DataItemIndex + 1 %>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#"><%# DataItemIndex + 1 %> <%# Eval("Heading") %></a>
    </h4>    
  </div>  
  <div id="accordionPanel<%# DataItemIndex + 1 %>" class="panel-collaspe collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labeledby="panel<%# DataItemIndex + 1 %>">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%# Eval("Panel") %>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: are you using nested repeaters?

Comment: I have a single repeater, and one transformation. I've updated the original question with some code.

Comment: so you should have more than one accordion on the page, I guess

Comment: At this moment i won't, but i'm trying to future proof it for the possibility of more than one accordion.

Comment: I'm reading this: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+web+part+properties. Is  it the GetValue("") that i would use?

Comment: I'm not sure GetValue will work as expected in transformation. Just try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark, not sure this is the best solution, but it should work for you. Add server side function into your transformation like this:

```
<script runat="server">
  protected string GetID()
    {      
      Control parent = this;      
      while ( (!(parent is CMSWebParts_Viewers_Documents_cmsrepeater)) && 
             (parent != null))
      {
        parent = parent.Parent;
      }      
      return (parent as CMSWebParts_Viewers_Documents_cmsrepeater).WebPartID;
    }
</script>
```

And call this method in your transformation like this:

```
<%# GetID() %>
```

Comment: This works, but the results aren't what i expected. GetID() returns repItems, which isn't a value in the web part properties panel. What other items are in the object parent?

Comment: That gave this error: [TempITemplate.Template]: http://server/CMSVirtualFiles/Transformations/=vg=710e85b9-17df-46b3-b848-535a7f041574/KFF.Accordion/AccordionPanels.ascx(11): error CS1061: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'WebPartID' and no extension method 'WebPartID' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MarkHandy change 'is' to 'as' in the return line. Sorry  about that.

Comment: I'd suggest registering a separate macro method (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Adding+custom+methods+to+transformations)... this way you'd generate the same code as many times as there are displayed items. If you are displaying one item only, that's fine, but if you have N, the code will be redundantly rendered N-1 times which could cause performance issues

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the Repeater's ClientID?

Try <%# Container.ClientID %> in this case Container should reference the Repeater the transformation is running on.

Comment: Thanks.

The Bootstrap javascript plugin for collapse panels needs the HTML ID.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't my preferred method, i wrote a quick js snippet. I try to avoid having too much JS.

```html
  /* Accordions */
  // we first detect if there is an accordion in the DOM, and if see we ensure that each is with it's own names space
  if ($accordion.length){
    // we need the ID of each accordion on the page which then becomes the data-parent value, which is needed to ensure we can isolate accordions
    $accordion.each(function(i,v){
      var $this = $(this),
          $id = $this.attr('id');
      // loop through each accordion panel
      $this.children('.panel').each(function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        $('.panel-title-link', $that).attr('data-parent', $id);
      });
    });
  }
```